# Escape string in mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, escaping, mysql-real-escape-string

I have a function to escape string in my OOP PHP project like this....

```
public function escape($string)
{
    $query = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $string);
    return $query;
}
```

is my code right? Or any one can give me a right way?

Comment: What is the problem? Have you tried this out? If so, what is the problem you're having with it?

Comment: You don't want to escape the entire QUERY only values, or it won't work. And what @aynber said.